# Jumping over the current loop, if error

Tags: php

I have

```
foreach($users as $user){ 
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadXml(file_get_contents($user["syncUrl"]));
}
```

if the content in the url on $user["syncUrl"], does so the loadXml() returns error (if it cant read), i would like it to just continue; and dont read the rest in the loop, until next loop (next $user).

Right now it is crashing, and outputs that it cant read because of wrong format. But i would like it to just jump over this and continue with the rest then.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hehe, you have it in your question: `continue;` is the command to skip the rest of the loop and start the next iteration.  Do error checking on $doc->loadXML and if it doesn't successfully load, then `continue;`.

So:

```
foreach($users as $user)
{ 
     $doc = new DOMDocument();
     $loaded = $doc->loadXml(file_get_contents($user["syncUrl"])); //Should return false on failure, true on success
     if($loaded === false)
     {
         continue;
     }
     //Do other stuff here if successfully loaded.
}
```

Might also be wise to use `DOMDocument::validate()` to validate the format (from the DTD) and `continue` if not valid.  You can also use `DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource()` to provide a source schema and use `DOMDocument::schemaValidate()` to validate the format from that schema.  You can also do this to have it validated on load:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadXML('etc');
```

Which would probably be necessary to have the loading function return false if the file stuff is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an `@` in front of the `$doc->loadXml` call, see if that works.

Comment: It works, but I would like to skip the rest, because now other errors are displaying because of $doc

Comment: Get what the `->loadXml` function returns and see if it's `false`, just like Phoenix says in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the error-suppression operator, `@`:

```
foreach($users as $user) { 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadXml(file_get_contents($user["syncUrl"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try and catch block?

```
foreach($users as $user){ 
    try{
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXml(file_get_contents($user["syncUrl"]));
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        continue;
    }
    //Rest of the code..
}
```

Comment: You would not want the `$doc = new DOMDocument();` inside the `try`